# Equivalent of pyrcc4 on KDE

Tags: python, pyqt4, opensuse, pykde, pyrcc

Am working on a pyqt app, done the ui via qt-designer 4.8.1, and generated the corresponding py file using pykdeuic4 (available on OpenSuse 12.2), but  can't find an equivalent for pyrcc4 to hadle the *.qrc files.

what's the equivalent tool/command?

**Edit:**

Most of the documentation on using QtDesigner with PyQt, indicates using pyuic4 / pyuic (which      on my platform is pykdeuic4), but as for the other tool pyrcc4 / pyrcc, I can't find an equivalent.

Am wondering, where can I even get the original tool from (pyrcc4)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no PyKDE-specific tool that corresponds with pyrrc4. The [KDE python bindings](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python) are built on top of PyQt, so you can just use pyrrc4 itself.

PyKDE only needs a specialized tool (pykdeuic4) for compiling ui files, because obviously KDE has lots of widgets that PyQt doesn't know about.

For OpenSuse, I believe the package that contains pyrrc is python-qt4-utils.

---

**NB:** The PyKDE project is moribund: [see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704170/984421).

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out all I needed was to install the extra package `python-qt4-utils` ontop of the existing `python-qt4`. Now, I have the sought after utilities in place.