# ImportError for kseparator in python file converted from .ui by pyqt ( using qt designer)

Tags: python, pyqt, importerror, qt-designer, pykde

The python file converted from .ui  created by qt designer shows
`ImportError: No module named kseparator`. code is

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.kseparator = KSeparator(Form)
        self.kseparator.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 231, 16))
        self.kseparator.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("kseparator"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))

from kseparator import KSeparator
```

The ui in qt designer consist only a kseperator and compiling shows:

```
from kseparator import KSeparator
ImportError: No module named kseparator
```

How can i add kseperator module. Is it a module to be installed separately like some python library? please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

FYI: as of Oct 2022, the PyKDE project appears to be completely dead. There have been [no commits for eight years](https://github.com/KDE/pykde5), and the outgoing maintainer has not been replaced (see: [PyKDE Future: Seeking a New Maintainer](https://blogs.kde.org/2015/03/29/pykde-future-seeking-new-maintainer)). So it's no longer possible to use any of the KDE widgets shown in Qt Designer (unless you're willing to take on the mainentance of the PyKDE project ;-).

---

The [KSeparator class](http://api.kde.org/4.0-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdeui/html/classKSeparator.html) is from KDE, which PyQt does not provide any direct support for.

If you want to use the KDE classes in your code, you will need to use [PyKDE](http://api.kde.org/pykde-4.1-api/).